# Transposition cipher implementation not working as intended

Tags: c++

I was trying to implement the basic transposition cipher that basically reverses each word while maintaining its position in the string but when I give it the input "MEET ME TOMORROW" it outputs "TEEM OMOT EM" instead of "TEEM EM WORROMOT".

```
string transposition(string input)
{
    string encryptedOutput = ""; int flag = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<input.length(); i++)
    {
        string temp = "";
        if(!isalpha(input[i]))
        {
            temp = input.substr(flag, i);
            flag = i+1;
            for(int j=0; j<temp.length(); j++)
            {
                encryptedOutput += temp[temp.length() - j - 1];
            }
            encryptedOutput += input[i];
        }
     }
     return encryptedOutput;
}
```

Comment: Just tracing through the function, outputting the values of the variables at each step, would have probably told you what's wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems with your code. First, the second parameter of

```
temp = input.substr(flag, i);
```

is the length of the substring, you should use instead:

```
temp = input.substr(flag, i-flag);
```

Second problem, you're not processing the last word of input, for that, I suggest you to changhe the `for` conditional to `i<=input.length()` so the program enters the if-code with the '\0' character of your string.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not worried about preserving spaces you can have some fun with stream iterators instead

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream iss("MEET ME TOMORROW");
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> iit(iss);
    std::istream_iterator<std::string> eos;

    std::ostringstream oss;
    std::ostream_iterator<std::string> oit(oss, " ");

    std::transform(iit, eos, oit, [](std::string const &s) { return std::string(s.crbegin(), s.crend()); });
    std::cout << oss.str();

    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/PlbXfb

```
TEEM EM WORROMOT
```